# Prevent 'Searches might be slow in non-indexed locations' banner from appearing

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, search, search-indexing

With a fast SSD I find that Windows Search indexing is superfluous and even slows certain operations down so I have disabled it.

However, when performing a search with a wide enough scope, Windows displays this banner at the top of the Explorer window:

[image: Searches might be slow in non-indexed locations banner]

You can click the X to close it, but it will reappear the next time you do a search.

The only methods I've seen for disabling it are to reinstate Windows Search which I obviously don't want to do.

Is there a registry key or other setting that I can change to modify this behaviour?

Comment: How did you disable it, disabled the Windows Search service in services.msc?

Comment: Via the Indexing Options dialog.

Comment: there is an option under Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> File Explorer Options -> Search. "Don't use the index when searching in file folders for system files (Searches might take longer)" maybe that one can help you out.

Comment: It's not system files I'm searching for though, it's typically across a folder structure containing 5,000-100,000 PDF/TIFF/XML etc. files, sometimes up to 50GB of data. 
 
The reason I disabled indexing was because it was making searches extremely slow on the SSD, something like 1000x slower than they should have been. Since disabling it the inherent speed of the drive allows relatively fast searching, but it's just the banner popup that's annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. In the end the solution was embarrassingly simple: just right-click on the banner and select 'Never show this again'.

Job done.

Why I didn't think to try that before I don't know.

Comment: I didn't think of it either, been getting annoyed by the message for 10 years. :)

Comment: This no longer works for Windows 10, but the comment above about setting File Explorer Options > Search does the job of eliminating the banner.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : In the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\InfoBarsDisabled`,
set the DWORD value of `LocationNotIndexed` to 1. Reboot and test.

My best advice, however, is to use third-party utilities for searching,
instead of Windows Explorer.

For searching file-names,
use the [Everything Search Engine](http://www.voidtools.com/), for instant as-you-type searching.

For searching the contents of files, use [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack),
which has many options like regular expressions, as well as
a Preview panel for viewing rapidly the found contexts for pinpointing
the files that are worth opening.
It also installs a shell-hook in Explorer, for invoking on a folder
with right-click.

Comment: In addition to `LocationNotIndexed`, set the DWORD value of `ServerMSSNotInstalled` to 1, in case Indexing service is disabled or removed.

Comment: grepWin is also very good.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers may not work if you have disabled the "Windows Search" service.

There is still a yellow message appearing, which you cannot disable using right-click. But there is a way to disable it:

- Go to Control Panel > Folder Options > "Search" tab
- Check "Don't use the index when searching in file folders for system files (search might take longer)".

(Yeah, the setting seems unrelated... Windows, as usual.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel > Folder Options > "Search" tab
Check "Don't use the index when searching in file folders for system files (search might take longer)".

This worked for me and is going to save TB's of disk space across the environment.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this registry tweak will fix that for you:

Go to here:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\InfoBarsDisabled

Set this key to the DWORD type with this value:
"ServerMSSNotInstalled" DWORD = 00000001

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to affect the banner.

Comment: I also tried this, without success too.